# How to do persistent http basic authentication with Watir?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, watir

I have added the full code below that I am using.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.start'http://user:password@siteaddress.com' 
b.driver.manage.window.maximize


Given /^I press "(.*)", with id "(.*)"$/ do |text, id|
  b.button(id: id, :text => text).when_present.fire_event :click
end

Then(/^checkbox validation$/) do
  b.link(data_search_text_english: 'Italy').click
end

Then(/^checkbox sailingxp$/) do
  b.link(data_search_text_english: 'comp').click
end

Then(/^check availability$/) do
  b.link(:href, "/vacation-options/bareboat-yacht-charter/destinations/mediterranean/italy/procida/availability").click
end

Then(/^check options and extras$/) do
  b.link(:class, "button lb-loading-spinner-booking-link lb_general_loading_spinner-processed").click
  sleep(8)

end
```

The problem I am facing is that after navigating these pages I am once again presented with the username and password popup but this time over https. Is there anyway I can set the username and password and forget about it? In that whenever it hits a page which requires authentication it automatically logs in. If this is not possible can someone tell me how I can enter a username and password to a popup and authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

We just use [`http_basic_authenticate_with`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html) for this:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: :index
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I have just noticed that when it asks for a username and password again it is over https. The first time the pop up occurs is over http when first navigating to the site.

Comment: Can you explain a little more please?

Comment: I use the following at the start of my code

require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.start 'http://admin:password@yourwebsite.com'

I then click through some search results and go through some pages. Then when I click a link which takes me to the booking flow of the site is where I am seeing a popup for authentication which is over https and not http

Comment: Updated my question with the full code. Hope someone can help!